How to add values in the input fields of calendar inside meeting scheduler automatically by the values set into the cookies in Hubspot?
I want values automatically add in the input fields of the calendar inside meeting scheduler in HubSpot by the values I have already set in the cookies. How can I do it.
I have tried targeting the form input fields using JavaScript but the form is in the iframe the script is not working.
The values are already set into the cookies I just want to them filled in to the input fields of the calendar in meeting scheduler automatically.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
